# Cannot add space between chapter and number of chapter

Tags: spacing

I want to give space between chapter (BAB) and the number of chapter(BAB), but I cannot add space. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={4cm,3cm},vmargin={4cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\mtcontentsname\contentsname\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\center\bfseries}{\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\thechapter}{1cm}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-1.5cm}{0cm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,beforeskip=2pt,entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}
\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}
\begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \frontmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{tes}
\end{document}
```

How to add space between BAB and the number of BAB? For example: BAB 1
[image]

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\center\bfseries}{\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}{1cm}{\large}` Note the `~`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX No, I consider this to be a simple typo and hence off-topic. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B let's closed it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was only a tilde missing, solved in comment